# Android: Telegram client searching for bot

Tags: android, telegram

I am working on a Telegram client (not a bot) plugin for an app to send messages in background to a bot. For this I am using the newest  [TDLib Api](https://core.telegram.org/tdlib). All is working fine, when I already initiated a chat with the official Telegram App, where I searched for the Bot by name and started to communicate with him.

The problem is, that I don't know, how to search for a Bot over the Api. Or maybe there is another way to get the information to start a chat with a bot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

First search for the bot by name:

```
TdApi.SearchPublicChat(mPrefs.getString(PreferenceKeys.BOT_NAME, "")
```

Then send the start message to the bot:

```
TdApi.SendBotStartMessage(mPrefs.getInt(PreferenceKeys.BOT_ID, 0), mPrefs.getInt(PreferenceKeys.MY_ID, 0), "" + System.currentTimeMillis())
```